# git bash config issues

Tags: git, ssh, config, git-bash

So im trying to get my git bash configured to where i open it and it prompts me for my password. I have followed the guidelines laid out in the website below, and i have my ssh keys generated, but i cant figure out what is wrong.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html#SetupSSHforGit-step-4-ssh-for-git

Here are the two files i can show you

.bashrc

```
 SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

config

```
Host https://bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

All 4 of my files are located below

C:\Users\Justin\.ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `https://` prefix if you want to authenticate using `ssh`. Use the config such as (described in the linked manual):

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Also provide output of `ssh -vvvT git@bitbucket.org` and note what is wrong, otherwise it is really unclear what are you asking.